# track browse history of your visitors

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I would like to know, what the typical behavior of users on my website is.

So I need to track a bunch of stuff, like what pages each user visits, than save them in a database and be able to view the information on a user to user basis.

eg User32111:

first visit 1.2.2013 - left the site after 15 sec
second visit ....
etc

I know google analytics can give you traffic reports but can it also break it down, like which IP/cookie holder did what on the site?

This would be useful to work out a typical user workflow and enhance usability accordingly.

But I am not sure if Analytics can do it out of the box, or I need to program my own.

Answer (score 1):

Google will never disclose as to whom visited your site ie there entire ip address,or if they logged in to google services there name and whatever,what google analytics does is that it will give you a general stat as to whom the visitor is ie country,city,the browser, even there service provider, from this data google assumes you can effectively use it to tweek your site marketing to suite your clientele.You can however create a goal in google analytics that will show you how your visitors are behaving as to the particular goal.i also suggest that you use "visitor flow" option as it would help you see a generalised way to show you what pages your visitors have been consistently visiting and which pages they have been droping.

Comment: thx. im not interested to see ip adresses. I just need to see page visits on a user basis. eg user123's browse history (of my site). Will goals do that for me? Or is goals, only on a visit basis not a user basis?

Comment: for example, I want to show a lightbox to anyone who has visited my product id=34566 but not to anyone else. That sort of thing. Im starting to think I have to program my own tracking :/

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to have more options over what is/isn't tracked, you could try using [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) instead. You get full control over which features to use/disable.

It even stores all data in your own database, so you can run any of your own queries to do pretty any reporting you can think of.

Comment: Thx I will look into it, perhaps it can do this task.

Comment: I see in another comment that you aren't interested in actual IP addresses, so you can choose the "Anonymize Visitors' IP Addresses" option.